# IIR filter simulink block diagram

Tags: iirf

I have just converted a butterworth prototype LPF to digital domain using bilinear transformation.

I'm currently struggling to build the model using basic building blocks like unit delays and gain blocks. Here is the transfer function:

```
H[z] = (0.083){(1+2z+z^2)/(0.368-1.036z+z^2)}.
```

My sampling period is 0.002 seconds.

Comment: what would you like to know? how to build the model with basic building blocks?

Comment: Yes. I want to know how to connect them so I can linearize the model and generate a bode plot using simulink